# Running x86_64 linux and getting ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, android, 32-bit, android-emulator

This is a separate error from [ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494305/error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecated) but I am getting the same error message.

I'm currently running:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- kernel Linux 4.4.0-45-generic(x86_64)
- Desktop environment LXDE
- 64-bit Java Server VM

I've seen previous results dealing with this same error and suggesting an update to a 64 bit Linux but clearly I already am. Running the avd with 32Bit forced results in the following error.

> Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_5_API_22' sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
>   [140514843576128]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not
>   found at /opt/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/qt/lib Could not launch
>   '/opt/Android/Sdk/tools/qemu/linux-x86/qemu-system-x86_64': No such
>   file or directory

the reason this is missing is because there is no linux-x86 folder only linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64

Is there any way I can get this running, preferably in the supported 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will solve your problem.
I had a freshly installed latest Android Studio and perform all basic steps to run a 'Hello World' project in emulator 
but had a same problem while running emulator from avd manager.
After that i tried running emulator from command line also but faced same problem.
After long debugging i came to find out that it was missing some core library, 
and then solved the problem by selecting checkbox and install emulator from Android Studio Options.
 *Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator*

And click Apply and Run project again.
Note :- If already Checked try to reinstall it. 
 
Now its working like a charm.[image: Sample Screenshot]